# PHP Edit Value inside Foreach Loop

Tags: php

Attempting to create a string from values inside a foreach loop, there really isn't a better way to do this, but it's not setting the string. I can't reset it to empty every iteration as I need it to continue on, I've read the duplicate questions and they don't answer *why* it doesn't work, any help is appreciated

This foreach just loops through and checks the format of the hours for businesses with multiple hours

`$hoursSpliced = ['5:00 AM - 11:00 AM', '5:00 PM - 2:00 AM']`

```
      $hoursFinal = '';
      foreach($hoursSpliced as $hour) {
        $hours = explode(' - ', $hour, 2);
        //If the hours match the format, we continue onward, no need to touch those
        if(preg_match($regex, $hour)) {
          $hoursFinal = $hoursFinal . $hour;
          continue;
        }
        //0 stores opening hours, 1 stores closing hours
        //Lower them so we can compare
        $hours[0] = strtolower(trim($hours[0]));
        $hours[1] = strtolower(trim($hours[1]));
        //If it's in the AM we add it to the end, same goes for PM, if there isn't one we assume it's PM
        if(strpos($hours[0], 'am') !== false) {
          $hoursOpen = array_map('trim', explode('am', $hours[0]));
          $hoursOpen[1] = 'am';
        } elseif(strpos($hours[0], 'pm') !== false) {
          $hoursOpen = array_map('trim', explode('pm', $hours[0]));
          $hoursOpen[1] = 'pm';
        } else {
          $hoursOpen = [$hours[0]];
          $hoursOpen[] = 'pm';
        }
        //Same thing as above for closing hours
        if(strpos($hours[1], 'am') !== false) {
          $hoursClosed = array_map('trim', explode('am', $hours[1]));
          $hoursClosed[1] = 'am';
        } elseif(strpos($hours[1], 'pm') !== false) {
          $hoursClosed = array_map('trim', explode('pm', $hours[1]));
          $hoursClosed[1] = 'pm';
        } else {
          $hoursClosed = [$hours[1]];
          $hoursClosed[] = 'pm';
        }
        $hoursFinal .= ", $hoursOpen[0] $hoursOpen[1] - $hoursClosed[0] $hoursClosed[1]";
      }
      $hoursFinal = trim(', ', $hoursFinal);
      dd($hoursFinal);
```

Comment: without knowing `$hoursSpliced` values, I doubt anyone can help.

Comment: Ah sorry, will add

Comment: Added it to the primary question

Comment: I see room for improvement.  Unneeded assignments etc...  For example, `$hoursFinal = $hoursFinal . $hour; continue;` is pointless.  But I would need some data to see what better way there is .. lol

Comment: And what's your `$regex` I can't remember if an empty regex counts as all

Comment: @Forbs - empty will/should/could throw and error for no delimiters.

Comment: `/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} (?P<meridiem>am|pm)/i` And maybe preg_match_all.  But that's assuming that is the format.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9aac18e2d5ffd8a8f36eca23cce18754588cbbe8  is that example the input format?  I can simplify this greatly.

Comment: Just so you guys can see it to make the logic of it, the regex is `$regex = '/^[0-9]{1,}:[0-9]{1,} ["P", "A"]["M"] - [0-9]{1,}:[0-9]{1,} ["A", "P"]["M"]/';`

Comment: I know I could clean that up in a few different ways, that's just much more readable than \d to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, took me a while
You got the trim backwards

```
  $hoursFinal = trim(', ', $hoursFinal);
```

Should be

```
   $hoursFinal = trim( $hoursFinal, ", ");
```

Comment: Nothing is embarassing, it's when you don't ask and it never works that's embarassing